# How to set custom options in an quote to create an order?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, custom-options

Here is the part of my code to create an order programmtically:

```
    //add products
$this->_getOrderCreateModel()->resetShippingMethod(true);
if (is_array($post['order']['add_products']))
    $this->_getOrderCreateModel()->addProducts($post['order']['add_products']);

$this->_getOrderCreateModel()
        ->saveQuote();

//apply custom product price
$productsData = array();
foreach ($this->_getOrderCreateModel()->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getproduct_id();
    foreach ($object['products'] as $srcProduct) {
        if ($productId == $srcProduct['product_id']) {
            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('tax/calculation/price_includes_tax') == 1) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($srcProduct['priceInclTax']);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($srcProduct['priceInclTax']); 

            } else {
                $item->setCustomPrice($srcProduct['priceExclTax']);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($srcProduct['priceExclTax']);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add the following code to above code but not work

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
    array(
        'product' => $product,
        'code' => '8',
        'value' => '5'
    )
));
```

anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You want to add custom option programetically into item, right?

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya yes

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add product with the custom option you want to used this code.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$Infobyreuest = array(
        'qty' => 1,
        'CUSTOM_OPTION_ID'=>'CUSTOM_OPTION_VALUE',
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($Infobyreuest));
```

**NOTE :** In above code you need to replace `'CUSTOM_OPTION_ID'=>'CUSTOM_OPTION_VALUE'` with your Id and value which you want to add.

Comment: i replace 'CUSTOM_OPTION_ID'=>'CUSTOM_OPTION_VALUE'  as '8' => '5', it this correct?

Comment: yes, but have you sure that 8 and 5 are corect value for custom options.

Comment: i replace this it works : 'options' => array( 8 => 5 )